# Update Database comment return 1 but there is no update

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update, android-context

Well I am updating my database with this code:

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put("tamam", true);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,
            Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
    return db.update(channel, newValues, "id =" + id , null);
```

it returns 1;

this is my return code:

```
if(msoru.isSolved()!= true){
            TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(getActivity());
            mDbHelper.createDatabase();
            mDbHelper.open();
            int truefalse = mDbHelper.updatecheck(mNum2);
            boolean truefalse2 =  msoru.isSolved();
```

but if I try to read new value it shows old value. I think there is no change

Comment: Maybe the old value was already "tanam", so it updates (here the count is 1), but with the old value (new value = old value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the database update method I should update also the my arrayclass with this

```
myArrayclass.get(mContext).setsolved(id);
            db.close();
```

at last it look like this:

```
public void updatecheck(int id) {


    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    int ok = 1;
    String sutun = "tamam";
    newValues.put(sutun, ok);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.update(tablename, newValues, "id = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    myArrayclass.get(mContext).setsolved(id);
    db.close();

}
```

Comment: What is your myArrayclass?

Comment: Sorry bro, it was old question I dont remember.